# source code skipping in C function, every LOC is executed but a few lines of code

Tags: c

I've designed a function in C that takes two files, XORs the contents of the first file with a 10 byte key and puts the result in a separate file. My program is based on enhancing LSB stenography using encryption. The XOR function mentioned above is meant to encrypt the plain text file and generate the cipher text file. The generated cipher text file is then used by another function which encodes it into the image. In this instance the XOR function works as intended, but the problem occurs during decoding. I've designed my program to decode the data from the image and place it in a text file (this will contain the cipher text previously encoded). Now when I use the same XOR function to decrypt the cipher text into plain text in the decoding phase, nothing but the print statements get executed in the function. The program logic is sound as I've tested the logic using a standalone program.

## include contains all the function prototypes and the header files required for execution.

**XOR Function:**

```
    #include<header.h>
void enc(FILE *source, FILE *destination)
{
    char text_buff, key[11];
    int i;
    printf("\nenter the key (max lenght 10): ");
    for(i = 0; ((key[i] = getchar()) != '\n'); i++);
    key[i] = '\0';
    char new;
    printf("\nThe string obtained: \t");
    i = 0;
    while((text_buff = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
    {

        new = text_buff ^ key[i];
        fputc(new, destination);
        i++;
        printf("%c",new);
        if(i==10)
            i=0;
    }
    printf("\nsuccessful\n");
}
```

**Main function:**

```
#include <header.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //declaring variables  and file pointers
    char *option = argv[1];
    FILE *source;       //source bmp image
    FILE *secretfile;       //secret text file
    FILE *newbmp;       //new bmp image
    FILE *secretmsg;    //decrypted data text file
    FILE *plain_text;   //Plain text1
    FILE *result_text;   //Plain text2
    //encode operations
    if(argc == 6)
    {
        //if argument passed is '-e'
        if(!strcmp(option, "-e"))
        {       
                if((plain_text = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL)
                {
                    FILE_ERROR(argv[2]);
                    EXIT;
                }
                if((source = fopen(argv[3], "r")) == NULL)
                {
                    FILE_ERROR(argv[3]);
                    EXIT;
                }

                if((secretfile = fopen(argv[4], "r+")) == NULL)
                {
                    FILE_ERROR(argv[4]);
                    EXIT;
                }

                if((newbmp = fopen(argv[5], "w")) == NULL)
                {
                    FILE_ERROR(argv[5]);
                    EXIT;
                }
                enc(plain_text,secretfile);
                encodeImg(source, secretfile, newbmp);
        }
        else
        {
            INVALID_ARGUMENTS;
            EXIT;
        }
    }

    //decode operations
    else if(argc == 5)
    {
        //if argument passed is '-d'
        if(!strcmp(option, "-d"))
        {
                if((newbmp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL)
                {
                    FILE_ERROR(argv[2]);
                    EXIT;
                }
                if((secretmsg = fopen(argv[3], "r+")) == NULL)
                {
                    FILE_ERROR(argv[3]);
                    EXIT;
                }
                if((result_text = fopen(argv[4], "w")) == NULL)
                {
                    FILE_ERROR(argv[4]);
                    EXIT;
                }
                decodeimg(newbmp, secretmsg);
                enc(secretmsg,result_text);
                fclose(secretmsg);
                fclose(result_text);


        }
        else
        {
            INVALID_ARGUMENTS;
            EXIT;
        }
    }
    //if no other argument is passed
    else
    {
        INVALID_ARGUMENTS;
        EXIT;
    }


}
```

**Header file contents:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "errorHandle.c"

//encode image main function
void encodeImg(FILE *source, FILE *secretfile, FILE *newbmp);

//size of image file(called from encodeImg)
int sizeImgFile(FILE *s1);

//size secret text file(called from encodeImg)
int sizeTxtFile(FILE *s2);

//string encode(called from encodeImg)
void stringEncode(char *String, FILE *source, FILE *newbmp);

//get character bits(called from stringEncode)
int get_bit(char byte, int bit);

//size encode(called from encodeImg)
void sizeEncode(int val, FILE *source, FILE *newbmp);

//secret encode(called from encodeImg)
void secretEncode(FILE *source, FILE *secretfile, FILE *newbmp);

//decode image main function
void decodeimg(FILE *newbmp, FILE *secretmsg);

//size decode(called from decodeimg)
void sizeDcp(FILE *newbmp, int *size);

//string decode(called from decodeimg)
void strDcp(FILE *newbmp, char *str, int size);

//secret decode(called from decodeimg)
void secretDcp(FILE *newbmp, FILE *secretmsg, int secretSize);

//Xor encryption(called from xor)
void enc(FILE *source, FILE *destination);

#define INVALID_ARGUMENTS printf("./a.out: missing file(s) operand\nTry - ./a.out <-e or -d> <plain text> <source bmp image> <secret text file> <new bmp image>\n") 

#define EXIT exit(1)

#define FILE_ERROR(file_name) printf("couldn't open file: %s\n", file_name) 

#define FILE_SIZE_ERROR printf("cannot perform operation: size of secret message is greater than the imagefile\n")
```

Comment: The computer doesn't arbitrarily skip lines of code. Step through it with a debugger.

Comment: please post the contents of `header.h` so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you debug it.

Comment: uploaded header file contents

Comment: The entire program works as intended, except the XOR function in the very end.

Comment: What is the sense of `i++` in the while loop? Every new pass resets i back to zero. You are always using `key[0]`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *option = argv[1];` Never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking that the command line parameter was actually entered by the user

Comment: regarding: `#define FILE_ERROR(file_name) printf("couldn't open file: %s\n", file_name)` This only says there was a problem what it says may not be the actual problem.  Suggest including `errno.h` then calling `strerror()` to obtain a pointer to the text reason the system thinks the problem occurred, then use that pointer in a `%s` output format specifier so the problem is displayed to the user.  Also, errr messages should be output to `stderr` not `stdout` suggest using `fprintf( stderr, "file: %s error message\n  %s", filename, strerror( errno ) );` for outputting the actual error

Comment: regarding: `#define INVALID_ARGUMENTS printf("./a.out: missing file(s) operand\nTry - ./a.out <-e or -d> <plain text> <source bmp image> <secret text file> <new bmp image>\n")`  a USAGE message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`,  Suggest using `fprintf()` similarly to my comment about error messages.  BTW; what is the meaning of `-d` and/or `-e`?

Comment: got it,. I actually fixed the i++ key[0] problem beforehand, I just uploaded a previous copy.

Comment: regarding: `printf("%c",new);`  the `printf()` function is very CPU expensive.  Suggest using: `putchar( new );`

Comment: -d stands for decode, -e stands for encode

Comment: the 'INVALID_ARGUMENTS` is only showing USAGE information for 5 arguments.  What about the part of the code that is expecting 6 arguments?

Comment: regarding: `while((text_buff = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
    {
        i = 0;
        new = text_buff ^ key[i];
        fputc(new, destination);
        i++;
        printf("%c",new);
    }`  if you have removed the statement: `i = 0;` then the code will soon be accessing `key[]` beyond the end of the array.  This is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: ./main.out -e ../Operation/plain.txt ../Operation/4.bmp ../Operation/secret.txt ../Operation/s4.bmp                                                                                  
where plain.txt is the source file, 4.bmp is the image on which stegenography is to be performed, secret.txt holds the cipher text after XOR operation and s4 is the new image where cipher text has been embedded.

Comment: regarding: `for(i = 0; ((key[i] = getchar()) != '\n'); i++);`  This is not enforcing the criteria that the 'key' is 10 characters or less. so the user could only enter a '\n' or enter more than 10 characters, resulting in a buffer overrun and the resulting undefined behavior which can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: I've modified the Xor function but the problem still persists.

Comment: strongly suggest using a debugger and stepping through your code so you can see what is actually happening

Comment: Until you use the debugger, you’ll be none the wiser. Use it. There’s precisely zero reason not to. You have to learn how to help yourself.

Comment: you guys have been really helpful, thanks

Comment: `for(i ...);` Bad semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while((text_buff = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
```

The `fgetc` function returns an `int`. But you chop it to a `char`, assign that to `text_buff`, and then compare *that* to `EOF`. That won't work. You are supposed to compare the return value of `fgetc` to `EOF`, not any other value.

There are two possibilities. Either some value of `char` maps to `EOF` or no value of `char` maps to `EOF`. If some value of `char` maps to `EOF`, then when you read that character in the middle of the file, you'll treat at as the end of the file. If no value of `char` maps to `EOF`, then you'll never detect the end of the file.

So this can't possibly work right.

Comment: I had doubts regarding this as well hence a wrote a standalone program using the logic stated in the function. In that case, the whole thing works like a charm. It accurately coverts plain text to cipher text and vice versa. The function skips all lines followed by printf("\nenter the key (max lenght 10): "); until it reaches printf("\nsuccessful\n"); which gets executed no problem. The functions exits, and then all the lines followed by the it's function call in the the main file also get executed with no problems whatsoever.